# Gauss sums over multiplicative subgroups

Tags: reference-request, nt.number-theory

Hello,

Is anyone here aware of a well-motivated exposition of the Bourgain-Glibichuk-Konyagin estimate for exponential sums (or Gauss sums) over multiplicative subgroups? If any of you has a write-up on the subject, I would be more than glad to have an opportunity to take a look at it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Well-motivated is in the eye of the beholder, but [Ben Green's notes](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.2075.pdf) seem to be good.

Comment: Igor,

Thanks for this mention. I did try pretty hard with that particular set of notes, though I might change one or two things if I were doing them again. I had some help from Bourgain and Lindenstrauss.

Comment: Thanks for writing the notes! This branch of mathematics is evolving so fast that one really needs a good guide to keep up (or at least not get left too far behind...)

Answer (score 2):

This theorem (and the relevant background material) are covered in Tao and Vu's Additive Combinatorics, see theorem 4.41 there.

Answer (score 2):

A very readable introduction is Kurlberg's paper - http://www.math.kth.se/~kurlberg/eprints/short_expsum.pdf